# Get number of requests in IIS from c# code

Tags: c#, iis

I am looking to get the number of requests that IIS currently has queued, programatically, in C#.

I'll also be looking to get the CPU usage as well...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

You will want to look at reading information from the performance counters of the system, depending on what you are looking for there are a number of counters that you can use.

This [MSDN article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0a6c9f07-a70c-4c3d-b93d-5dfef593c744.mspx?mfr=true) shows all IIS6 performance counters there is a similar one for IIS7 that you should be able to find.

For the CPU usage, there are a few ways you can go about this as well.  Depending on if you want total CPU usage, or a per-process CPU usage.

Also, here is [a tutorial](http://asp.dotnetheaven.com/howto/doc/PCRead.aspx) on reading from the process counter.

Answer (score 2):

On IIS7 you could use Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly, WorkerProcess object has GetRequests method, look at [WorkerProcess.GetRequests Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.workerprocess.getrequests%28VS.90%29.aspx)

And for CPU usage you could use Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPoolCpu property of ApplicationPool class, alltough I am not sure that there are information about current CPU usage, look at [ApplicationPool.Cpu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpool.cpu%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.WEB.ADMINISTRATION.APPLICATIONPOOL.MANAGEDRUNTIMEVERSION%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-)

Microsoft.Web.Administration is great :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, especially the classes that start with `PerformanceCounterXXX`