# Get Number of Requests Queued in IIS using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, azure

I need to collect following two informations from WebRole running IIS-8 on Azure.

1. Number of requests queued in IIS
2. Number of requests current being processed by worker

Since we are on Azure cloud service, I believe it would be better to stick together with default IIS configuration provided by Azure.

**Approach 1: Use WorkerProcess Request Collection**

```
    public void EnumerateWorkerProcess()
    {
        ServerManager manager = new ServerManager();
        foreach (WorkerProcess proc in manager.WorkerProcesses)
        {
            RequestCollection req = proc.GetRequests(1000);
            Debug.WriteLine(req.Count);
        }
    }
```

**Cons:**

Requires RequestMonitor to be enabled explicitly in IIS.

**Approach 2: Use PerformanceCounter class**

```
    public void ReadPerformanceCounter()
    {
        var root = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/PerfCount.txt");
        
        PerformanceCounter counter = new PerformanceCounter(@"ASP.NET", "requests current", true);
        float val = counter.NextValue();
        using (StreamWriter perfWriter = new StreamWriter(root, true))
        {
            perfWriter.WriteLine(val);
        }
    }
```

**Cons:**
Requires higher privilege than currently running IIS process.

P.S. **There has been a [four years old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783559/get-number-of-requests-in-iis-from-c-sharp-code) but not answered well.**

Comment: Can't you just capture this through Azure Diagnostics and have this data persisted in `WADPerformanceCountersTable`?

Comment: Why do you think that when working with Azure cloud services you work with IIS 7 ? This is only true for OS Family 2. OS Family 3 & 4 are Based on Windows Server 2012 and 2012R2 respectively, which have IIS 8 and 8.5. This is one. Second is, why do you think it is not feasible or wise to tweak your IIS on a cloud service ?! People are doing it for years.

Comment: @GauravMantri, I followed your advice & enabled WAD. I am using Azure SDK 2.5 so it was a charm.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have been reading this counter `\ASP.NET\Requests Queued` and this value is always zero. I know our application is serving 100s of requests/ sec. So counter value is definitely wrong. Am I reading correct counter to measure requests queued up in IIS AppPool.